# why the recurrence action in power automate not working?

Tags: power-automate

I have configured the power automate "recurrence" action to execute every week Monday through Friday at 9.00 am IST. I have attached the screenshot for reference. [image]

```
Interval is set to 1
Frequency is set to Week
Time zone is set to UTC+5:30(which is IST time zone)
Start time: 2024-01-15T03:30:00.000Z(equivalent to 9 am IST)
```

In the "preview" we could see that the flow is supposed to run as per the requirement. This configuration was configured on 14th Jan 2024, and the flow was expected to execute at `9.00 am IST from 15th Jan 2024` onwards. But it didn't.

I have noticed that if I set 2 in the interval, then preview says that the work flow will execute every two weeks. So, does that mean if I set 1 as the interval, then the work flow will execute every 1 week rather than every week, Monday through Friday? Or, should we go with the face value of the "preview" that says that if the interval is set to 1 then the flow will execute as shown in the Preview?

Please suggest

Comment: It is fine as you have it. I suspect the start time may be the culprit here. You should see it run tomorrow.

Comment: Ok, will keep u updated here